# File Transfer returns weird characters

Tags: c++, sockets, file, tcp, transfer

So I'm trying to create a simple file transfer method. It's completely working for small files (a few bytes). But if I want to transfer a file with the size of 2 kB, it returns unicode characters instead of that what's inside the file.

Server:

```
void DownloadFile(SOCKET Socket){
    if(Socket == NULL){
        return;
    }
    while(1){
        char filename[1024];
        recv(Socket, filename, sizeof(filename), 0);
        if(filename[0] == '.'){
            break;
        }
        FILE* fp = fopen(filename, "r");
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        long FileSize = ftell(fp);
        char GotFileSize[1024];
        _itoa_s(FileSize, GotFileSize, 10);
        send(Socket, GotFileSize, 1024, 0);
        rewind(fp);


        long SizeCheck = 0;
        char* mfcc;

        if(FileSize > 1499){
            mfcc = (char*)malloc(1500);
            while(1){
                if(SizeCheck >= FileSize){
                    fclose(fp);
                    Sleep(500);
                    free(mfcc);
                    break;
                }
                fread_s(mfcc, 1499, sizeof(char), 1499, fp);
                send(Socket, mfcc, FileSize, 0);
                SizeCheck += strlen(mfcc);
            }
        }
        else{
            mfcc = (char*)malloc(FileSize + 1);
            fread_s(mfcc, FileSize, sizeof(char), FileSize, fp);
            send(Socket, mfcc, FileSize, 0);
            fclose(fp);
            Sleep(500);
            free(mfcc);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

Client:

```
void DownloadFile(SOCKET Socket){
    if(Socket == NULL){
        return;
    }
    while(1){
        printf("Input local filename: ");
        char localfile[1024];
        gets_s(localfile, 1024);
        if(localfile[0] == '.'){
            send(mySocket, localfile, sizeof(localfile), 0);
            break;
        }
        printf("Input remote filename: ");
        char filename[1024];
        gets_s(filename, 1024);
        if(filename[0] == '.'){
            send(mySocket, filename, sizeof(filename), 0);
            break;
        }
        send(mySocket, filename, sizeof(filename), 0);
        char GotFileSize[1024];
        recv(mySocket, GotFileSize, 1024, 0);
        long FileSize = atoi(GotFileSize);
        long SizeCheck = 0;
        FILE *fp = fopen(localfile, "w");
        char* mfcc;
        if(FileSize > 1499){
            mfcc = (char*)malloc(1500);
            while(1){
                if(SizeCheck >= FileSize){
                    fclose(fp);
                    Sleep(500);
                    free(mfcc);
                    break;
                }
                recv(mySocket, mfcc, 1499, 0);
                fprintf(fp, "%s", mfcc);
                SizeCheck += strlen(mfcc);
            }
        }
        else{
            mfcc = (char*)malloc(FileSize + 1);
            recv(mySocket, mfcc, FileSize, 0);
            fprintf(fp, "%s", mfcc);
            fclose(fp);
            Sleep(500);
            free(mfcc);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I transfer this file:

```
Testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
```

The transfered file contains this:

```
Testtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º««««««««îþîþtesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesº««««««««îþîþttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttestesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttesttest
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º
ð­º««««««««îþîþ
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why this:

```
            fread_s(mfcc, 1499, sizeof(char), 1499, fp);
            send(Socket, mfcc, FileSize, 0);
```

you are sending FileSize bytes but you don't even know how much you've read. Check the return value of the read, don't use strlen() for this for you don't know if the file contains 0 bytes.

Comment: For this kind of problem I usually suggest people to print values in hex for better readability: fprintf(fp, "0x%x", mfcc);

Comment: Well, I found that the default socket size is 1500 bytes. So if the file's larger than 1500 bytes, split it in chunks. I might've done it wrong though.

@Karlphillip: I'll try that.

Comment: @karl but what use is it to print the memory offset of the buffer? (mfcc is a pointer..)

Comment: @Waza: if you call `send` you need to tell it how much you want to send. If you call `read`, it tells you how much it actually read. So take the return value of the read, and pass it to send instead of FileSize. (also, please develop a habit of checking all return values, always)

Comment: btw, if you just `write` to the socket, the network stack will do this chopping for you.

Comment: @Mvds: With read, I take it that you mean fread? Or am I mistaken? Also, it works the way it is if FileSize < 1500. It's just the part when FileSize >= 1500. My compiler can't find write() nor read(). What header file do I need?

Comment: @waza: yes, I'm referring to how these things work in general; the following in no way replaces a proper explanation, but in short: `read`-like functions give the number of bytes read, and you must give `send`- or `write`-like functions the number of bytes you want to write. Try `fwrite` or `fwrite_s` in your environment. `write` like functions treat the socket and data as a stream, `send` like functions treat it as a channel to send packets on. functions starting with `f...` generally work on stream pointers, functions without the `f` generally work on the raw fd.

Comment: @waza: I think you have enough pointers to go and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. A newline is 2 bytes in size, but my program only counted it as one. I figured this because the difference between Filesize and Sizecheck is in fact the amount of lines in the file.

New loop:

```
char* mfcc;
mfcc = (char*)malloc(FileSize + 1);
while(SizeCheck {issmallerthan} FileSize){
    int Received = recv(mySocket, mfcc, FileSize, 0);
    int Written = fwrite(mfcc, sizeof(char), Received, fp);
    SizeCheck += Written;
    for(int i = 0; i {issmallerthan} Written; i++){
        if(mfcc[i] == '\n'){
            SizeCheck += 1;
        }
    }
}
fclose(fp);
free(mfcc);
```

The sender part is like this one.

Thanks for the help all. :3

Case closed. :D